# I've installed JBoss Tools 4.1.1.Final for Eclipse Kepler but the Arquillian plugin is nowhere to be found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jboss-arquillian, jboss-tools, eclipse-marketplace

A couple of months ago, using the Eclipse Marketplace on a fresh installation of Eclipse Kepler (the J2EE bundle, to be more specific) I've installed JBoss Tools 4.1.1.Final, but **now that I need the Arquillian plugin I notice that it's not installed**.
As far as I can tell, it should be in the aforementioned JBoss Tools bundle. Does anyone know if that's the case or if I'm supposed to get another bundle or fetch the plugins from another source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this *jbosstools* install option instead:

Help > Install New Software… > Work with:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/

For more information or other releases checkout their page

http://tools.jboss.org/